# PHP Mailer: XLSX file coruplted when sending from html file

Tags: php, phpmailer, xlsx

I am currently having a problem with my PHP code as it corrupts the data/xlsx file when exporting it from HTML.

i am viewing PHP Mailer scripts which has multiple pages connected to it.

This is my PHP XLS Function.

```
this->_request->download ? true : false;
$htmlPath   = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../public/reports/html/") . "/" . $fileName;
$fileSource = file_get_contents($htmlPath);
preg_match('!<title>([^<]+)!', $fileSource, $title);
$title = trim($title[1]);
if (stristr($fileSource, '<graph>')) {
$fileSource = preg_replace('!<graph>[^<]+</graph>!is', '', $fileSource);
file_put_contents($htmlPath, $fileSource);
}
file_put_contents($htmlPath,preg_replace('!<title>[^<]+</title>!is','',$fileSource));
$reader  = new PHPExcel_Reader_HTML;
$content = $reader->load($htmlPath);

// Pass to writer and output as needed
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($content, 'Excel2007');
$download  = 1;
// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
//header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
$fileName  = str_replace(' ', '-', ($title . "-" . date('Y-m-d')));
if ($download) {
// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
//  header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); // always modified
header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; 

filename=' . $fileName . ".xlsx")
```

this is my caller function

```
if ($reportRow->reportString) {
$reportRow->reportString = stripslashes($reportRow->reportString);
if (!stristr($reportRow->reportString, '</body>'))
$reportRow->reportString = $reportRow->reportString . "</table></body></html>";
$fileName = time() . rand(111, 222);
$htmlPath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../public/reports/html/") . "/" . $fileName;
if ($headerPath) {
$reportRow->html_string = preg_replace('!(\s*</htmlpageheader>)!', '$1<img width="100%"  style="clear:both" id="headerPath" src="' . $headerPath . '" />', $reportRow->html_string);
}
$corp_name = preg_replace('!\s+!',' ',$userSessionData->corp_name);
$reportRow->reportString = preg_replace_callback(
'!<title>([^<]+)!is',
function($matches) use ($corp_name){
return '<title>' . $corp_name . '_' . preg_replace('!\s+!',' ',$matches[1]);
},
$reportRow->reportString
);
file_put_contents($htmlPath, $reportRow->reportString);
$kilobites = filesize($htmlPath);
$kilobites = $kilobites / 1024;
$kilobites = 0;
if ($ifXLS) {
echo json_encode(array(
'reportPath' => '/helper/file-To-xls/fileName/' . $fileName,
'error' => false
));
```

would anyone have any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSV functions or PHPExcel to do it straight forward

or you can try like below

```
<?php
$file="1.xls";
$html="<table><tr><td>Col1</td><td>Col2</td></tr></table>";
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
echo $html;
?>
```

The header for .xlsx files is Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet if you prefer to export it as .xlsx